# Increase development speed of ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, open-source, asp.net-2.0

I am curious to know that how we can make web site development much faster. I am specific about asp.net.

As far as my knowledge is concern, we can make asp.net website development faster by

Using Log4Net - to capture logging information Entity framework - to increase database operation speed.

So, is there other tools also which we can use to optimize the development process?

If you have used in any of your project, whether it was a small project or large.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this tools/libs (only free, I'm not mention about commercial like Resharper):

**Ghostdoc** - for generating comments - http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx (free)

**Microsoft Enterprise Library** - good library for validators, caching, logging and other purpose - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650466.aspx

**Nhibernate** (not Entity Framework if you want to use it in asp.net-2.0)

**Fiddler 2.0** - external tool to analyze your page traffic (good for tracking problems in ajax, and improve performance)

**Firexox + Firebug + Yslow** - best way to test page performance and debug it

**IETester** - program for test your page on various versions of IE (sometimes you have to create page compatibile with IE 6-8 ;/) - http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

And if it is possible in your project - upgrade asp.net version to at least 3.5 - it could improve your coding speed a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Something we are looking at using in future projects for doing layouts is the [960 Grid system](http://960.gs/).

[jQuery](http://jquery.com), obviously, for better, easier JavaScript.

I like the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) for ease of use of its' widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate and a DI framework (StructureMap or Windsor).

Comment: I don't think that MVC helps to generate code faster. Code has higher quality, could be better tested, is more reusable. But writing code is sometimes much slower.